# "I would like to know and TO get some info" or I would like to know and get some info"

Tags: prepositions

Should I add the preposition TO right after I already mentioned it first time in the sentence "I would like to..."

For example:

> "I would like to know and **TO** get some info"

Vs:

> or I would like to know and get some info"

Comment: The first infinitive marker *to* is implicitly applied to the second verb *get*, so the second option is the best.

Comment: I would suggest that if the meaning in context is the same, don't add unnecessary words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your examples are correct, understandable, and generally used.

Using

> to *verb* and to *verb*

is more strictly parallel in construction, but for efficiency often gets shortened especially when the two actions are related.

> I would like to ride on a bus and to sleep on a feather bed.

would mean there are two things you would like to do: ride on a bus, and sleep on a feather bed, which may be two unrelated actions.

> I would like to ride on a bus and sleep on a feather bed.

can mean you want to sleep on a feather bed which is on a bus.

Answer (score 1):

I think both of them are correct

you use first sentence when you want to emphasize your request